# Primitive type error when saving a node with a custom datetime field

Tags: 8, entities, database

I have a custom module providing a few fields to nodes - a checkbox, datetime field and a select.

Previously the datetime field only contained date and the node would save correctly however since trying to change this to also accept time the node won't save and returns the 'This value should be of the correct primitive type.' error.

I get no issues when adding the field itself and have tried completely removing the field from the entity (and removing just the datetime piece to check the checkbox and select are behaving) but get nothing.

My class `extends FieldItemBase` and has what I think are correct property definitions:

```
public static function propertyDefinitions(StorageDefinition $storage) {
    $properties = [];
    $properties['enabled'] = DataDefinition::create('boolean')
      ->setLabel(t('Enabled'));
    $properties['date_time'] = DataDefinition::create('datetime_iso8601')
      ->setLabel(t('Date and Time'));
    $properties['value'] = MapDataDefinition::create('string')
      ->setLabel(t('State'));
    return $properties;
  }
```

Also a correct schema (hopefully):

```
public static function schema(StorageDefinition $storage) {

    $columns = [];
    $columns['enabled'] = [
      'type' => 'boolean',
      'not null' => 'true',
      'mysql_type' => 'tinyint',
    ];
    $columns['date_time'] = [
      'type' => 'varchar',
      'length' => 20,
    ];
    $columns['value'] = [
      'type' => 'text',
      'length' => 255,
      'not null' => 'true',
    ];
    return [
      'columns' => $columns,
      'indexes' => [],
    ];
  }
```

The fields are provided in another class which `extends widgetBase`. The field giving me problems is set out as such:

```
$element['date_time'] = [
      '#type' => 'datetime',
      '#title' => t('On'),
      //'#default_value' => isset($items[$delta]->date) ? DrupalDateTime::createFromTimestamp(strtotime($items[$delta]->date)) : NULL,
    ];
```

Within `public function formElement(FieldItemListInterface $items, $delta, array $element, array &$form, FormStateInterface $formState)`.

The rest of the custom field *stuff* provided by the module seems to all be correct as the field is added, no other errors given etc and everything worked correctly before attempting to implement the time aspect of datetime.